# How do I use DateTime.TryParse() for non-English languages like Arabic?

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, globalization

I need to convert strings to DateTime objects that are in non-English languages. I've seen many examples of converting DateTime to strings in other languages, but not the other way around.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("ar-AE");    // Arabic - United Arab Emirates

string sample = "الاربعاء 16 مارس 2011"; // Arabic date in Gregorian calendar
DateTime result;
DateTime expected = new DateTime(2011, 3, 16);   // the expected date
bool b;

b = DateTime.TryParse(sample, provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);

Assert.IsTrue(b);
Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
```

Additionally, I need to handle strings that are in other calendars. This is what I tried and it doesn't seem to work either.

```
CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("ar-AE");    // Arabic - United Arab Emirates
provider.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new System.Globalization.HijriCalendar();
// Wednesday, March 16, 2011, 11 Rabi second in 1432
string sample = " ‏11 ربيع ثاني 1432 ";
DateTime result;
DateTime expected = new DateTime(2011, 3, 16);   // ?
bool b;

b = DateTime.TryParse(sample, provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);

Assert.IsTrue(b);
Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think there is a small problem with arabic unicode normalization (or something similar)... I think the word "wednesday" can be written in two ways... If you try expected.ToString("ddd dd MMMM yyyy", provider) you'll see that the string seems the same, but isn't binary-equal. Your 2nd character is 0x0627 (ARABIC LETTER ALEF), the ToString one is 0x0623 (ARABIC LETTER ALEF WITH HAMZA ABOVE). I don't know anything of arab, but I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the exact format, you can force its use with `TryParseExact`:

```
b = DateTime.TryParseExact(sample, "dddd d MMMM yyyy", provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);
```

However, in your case, this does not work. To find the problem, let’s try the other way round:

```
Console.WriteLine(expected.ToString("dddd d MMMM yyyy", provider));
```

And the result is “الأربعاء 16 مارس 2011”, which (you can probably read that better than me) differs from your input in one character: .NET uses (and expects) hamza, your input does not have it. If we modify the input in this way, everything works:

```
CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("ar-AE");    // Arabic - United Arab Emirates

string sample = "الأربعاء 16 مارس 2011"; // Arabic date in Gregorian calendar
DateTime result;
DateTime expected = new DateTime(2011, 3, 16);   // the expected date
bool b;

b = DateTime.TryParse(sample, provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);

Assert.IsTrue(b);
Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
```

Comment: I don't read Arabic either, and it turns out the words are days of the week and month, etc. Once I had specified a format string it worked rather well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime result = DateTime.Parse("الاربعاء 16 مارس 2011", new CultureInfo("ar-JO"));
```

But you can check the documentation : [CultureInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: That didn't work on my machine, even though we moved to Jordan?

Comment: Just tried your example and got this: "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0." I literally copy/pasted your example. What gives?

Comment: Do you know which languages will you use ?

Comment: I'm reading documents in various languages, and yes I know which language/culture is appropriate for each document.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
int Year, DayOfMonth;
string Month;
string[] Months = new string[] {"ينایر","فبرایر","مارس","ابریل","مایو",...};//these texts are writen with persian keyboard,change the ی  with ي ,its really hard with my keymap
string[] Splits = Input.Split(" ");
foreach(string Split in Splits)
{
    if(Months.Contains(Split))
    {
        Month = Months.IndexOf(Split);
    }
    else
    {
        int Number;
        if(int.TryParse(Split, out Number))
        {
            if(Number<32)
            {
                DayOfMonth=Number;
            }
            else
            {
                Year=Number;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if your going to support multiple calendars:
you should add all the calendars months in order in that array.
after december there should be the next calendar months ( rabi-ol-avval, rabi-ol-thani, ...)
then

int CalendarId = Month / 12;
Month %= 12;