# Importing Excel DateTime columns with Arabic formats

Tags: c#, excel, localization, import, arabic

I have a problem similar to the one described here: [How do I use DateTime.TryParse() for non-English languages like Arabic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330885/how-do-i-use-datetime-tryparse-for-non-english-languages-like-arabic?rq=1#comment6020173_5330885)
But the problem is the input string for parsing comes from the excel file. When tested on Windows 7 the string is written with the "لأ" character, but when testing on XP with the same regional setttings, the strings I get contain only "لا" symbol.
From answer to the linked post I see "I think there is a small problem with arabic unicode normalization (or something similar)... I think the word "wednesday" can be written in two ways... If you try expected.ToString("ddd dd MMMM yyyy", provider) you'll see that the string seems the same, but isn't binary-equal. Your 2nd character is 0x0627 (ARABIC LETTER ALEF), the ToString one is 0x0623 (ARABIC LETTER ALEF WITH HAMZA ABOVE)"
So my question isv - how can this be avoided, how can I be sure that I get the right symbol the .Net expects "لأ"?

Thanks is advance

Comment: If you "have exactly the same problem" then why did you ask?

Comment: Because the linked question does not provide any solutions for my case. The anwers there say "change your input" basicly. In my case, I have no control over my input, since it comes from Excel through OLDDBAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up with hard-coded soluton. When we parse the input we check for this symbol and replace it with the expected of the .net DateTime parser.