# convert arabic date string to datetime object in c#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, windows-runtime

I have date time in string format coming from server which I can't change.

DateTime is coming in this format and is in Arabic :

14-يوليه-2015 04:44:51 م

and I am unable to convert it in datetime object in c#.

I have tried these so far.

```
DateTime latest = Convert.ToDateTime(latestTables.Result.StaticTable[i].dtUpdTime, new CultureInfo("en-US"));

DateTime latest = DateTime.ParseExact(latestTables.Result.StaticTable[i].dtUpdTime, "dd-t hh:mm:ss yyyy-MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 

DateTime latest = Convert.ToDateTime(latestTables.Result.StaticTable[i].dtUpdTime, new CultureInfo("ar-SA"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Having tried to paste Arabic date strings into my answer I have discovered that characters are sometimes reordered due to RTL issues. In particular a `DateTime` formatted using the format `d-MMMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` will have the initial `d-` part moved to the end (to the left) which is exactly how the string in your question appear (e.g. from right to left: month, year, time, AM/PM specifier and then day which seems weird). So I assume that your string really uses the more natural format `d-MMMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`.

The issue that you are having is that you need to use the correct calendar. You have tried to use the `ar-SA` culture but the default calendar for this is a Hirji calendar. You need to use a Gregorian calendar with the correct month names. To change the calendar you need to create a new `CultureInfo` and choose the correct calendar. In your case it seems that you need to use the "Localized" calendar at index 5 of the `OptionalCalendars` property:

```
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-SA");
cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = cultureInfo.OptionalCalendars[5];
```

You can then parse your string using this code (where I create the string in a way that does not change it when I paste it into my browser):

```
var dateTimeString = new String(new[] {
  '1',
  '4',
  '-',
  'ي',
  'و',
  'ل',
  'ي',
  'و',
  '-',
  '2',
  '0',
  '1',
  '5',
  ' ',
  '0',
  '4',
  ':',
  '4',
  '4',
  ':',
  '5',
  '1',
  ' ',
  'م'
});
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeString, cultureInfo);
```

The resulting `DateTime` is:

```
2015-07-14T16:44:51
```

If you want to use `DateTime.ParseExact` the format is `d-MMMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, "d-MMMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", cultureInfo);
```

You should also consider using `DateTime.TryParse` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` for better flow of code if you encounter an invalid formatted string.

Comment: `+1` for your effort. I wasn't _really_ think to get every character in a unicode explorer or something and put them in a string constructor as an array. Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

This text translates to "14 - July 04:44:51 -2015 m" according to google translate : [Google Tranlate Link](https://translate.google.co.uk/?ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#ar/en/14-%D9%8A%D9%88%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%87-2015%2004%3A44%3A51%20%D9%85). You can easily parse this using [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330885/how-do-i-use-datetime-tryparse-for-non-english-languages-like-arabic) might help further

Comment: ok so you want to say that this will convert it:

DateTime.ParseExact(latestTables.Result.StaticTable[i].dtUpdTime, "dd - MMM hh:mm:ss -yyyy t", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: Did you convert the text before running the parseExact function?

Comment: Convert? Convert to what?