# How to set order for arabic string in html

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

How can I change the the order of a datetime written in arabic numbers?
I have requirement to use  Arabic string and I am using following code in c# which is written in Arabic

```
std.Inner Text = "17-02-2016";
```

This string is Arabic number.
But when I view this page result is like this ٢٠١٦-٠٢-١٧
(17-02-2016).I want result in same order like `2016-02-17` in arabic not in english

Comment: you could use the css property  direction: rtl;
for more reference visit
 https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/direction/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change date format from DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074671/how-to-change-date-format-from-dd-mm-yyyy-or-mm-dd-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: i already set the direction

Comment: but its not working.How can i do this

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply just pullback the actual explicit format from DateTime?

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

This really depends on wher eyou are doing this, if you first having to convert Arabic text to a DateTime then look at this:

[Stack Overflow: Convert arabic date string to datetime object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427498/convert-arabic-date-string-to-datetime-object-in-c-sharp)

Comment: This not optimal, yes the format is dd-MM-yyyy which means start writing the day part first, if I make it yyyy-MM-dd to display is in rtl I’d need to start writing the year first in input fields. @LimpingNinja