# DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact() with non English characters

Tags: c#, parsing, datetimeoffset

I'm basing my question on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330885/how-do-i-use-datetime-tryparse-for-non-english-languages-like-arabic)

```
string str = @"30-מאי-18 14:18:15 +03:00";
DateTimeOffset res;
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("he-IL");
culture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new System.Globalization.HebrewCalendar();
if (DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(str, 
    "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss", culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out res) )
     ///do stuff
```

The Hebrew string "מאי" means "May" (it some kind *hebrish*, which is English words that have been adopted into Hebrew or simply written in Hebrew characters)

So I think here `HebrewCalendar()` has no effect because according to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.hebrewcalendar(v=vs.71).aspx) it corresponds the to the actual Hebrew months

`DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact()` does not work for me, am I missing something?

It does not work with or without `HebrewCalendar()`

Comment: Just for future readers, could you clarify your exact question?

Comment: @TEK Edited, im hoping that the question is clear now

Comment: @styx you are trying to parse a string that *doesn't* match the pattern. At the very least you need to add the am/pm placeholders to the pattern. I think they are `tt`. Unless it's the month??? In any case you need to use a pattern that matches the value. `"30-מאי-18 14:18:15 +03:00"` looks nothing like `"dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: Note: `Exact`. You have to exactly match the format string you provide.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how can i find out what is the pattern that match my string

Comment: @styx I can't tell you because when I copied that string into Linqpad, it changed. It even changes as I move the cursor in it. I even tried to use `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss zzzz",culture)` and got something different again. Unicode magic, but that means I don't really know what the string looks like. I'd suggest you try various combinations in `ToString()` until you come up with one that looks the same as the original. Use that as the format in the parse string