# convert "ספטמבר 15, 2018 בשעה 10:20 am" to datetime C#

Tags: c#, datetime

i have a REST api that store date time in string:
 "ספטמבר 15, 2018 בשעה 10:20 am" 
the above include the system language (in this case Hebrew). is there any way to convert this to C# DateTime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use DateTime.TryParse() for non-English languages like Arabic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330885/how-do-i-use-datetime-tryparse-for-non-english-languages-like-arabic)

Comment: What is the meaning of the word beetween `10:20` and `2018` exactly? I try to translate it to English with Google Translate and it says: "at".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert string to DateTime you can use a similar sintax:

```
string dateInput = "ספטמבר 15, 2018 בשעה 10:20 am";
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateInput);
```

If you want to use a different culture use:

```
CultureInfo MyCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("sql-Al");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would convert all the Hebrew text to English text, and then pass a suitable format string to DateTime.TryParseExact

For example

```
 string dateInEnglish = dateInHebrew.Replace("ספטמבר", "September"). Replace("בשעה","")
```

Would strip out all the Hebrew from that date, although in practice I would use a regex.

Check out the documentation on TryParseExact to create a suitable format string:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__